# Watir - hover method does not work on aws windows box firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, cucumber, watir

On Mac OS working perfect, but when I am running on AWS Windows box (not headless) hover does not work.

And I hover over "#attr1" of an element with css

```
#features/step_definitions/home_page.rb:49
  Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
  ./features/step_definitions/home_page.rb:50:in `/^I hover over "([^"]*)" of an element with css$/'
  features\CampaignTest.feature:95:in `And I hover over "#attr1" of an element with css'
And I hover over "#attr2" of an element with css
```

I had same problem when i was running same test on chrome but i fix it by maximizing window.

```
$browser.window.resize_to(1450, 1200)
$browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
```

(this wasn't fully maximizing chrome so i just added link above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a Net::ReadTimeout exception, it means it is probably a browser driver bug. This is assuming you were not getting the same error in chrome.

Your exact code and a full stack trace (run your cuke with --backtrace) would help considerably in tracking down the root cause. If we can reproduce it, I can help submit the bug report.

Comment: "irb(main):001:0> require 'watir'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> browser=Watir::Browser.new
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x7ab859b2 url="about:blank" title="">
irb(main):004:0> browser.element(:css,'#nav-channels').exists?
=> true
irb(main):005:0> browser.element(:css,'#nav-channels').visible?
=> true
irb(main):006:0> browser.element(:css,'#nav-channels').hover
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native inte
raction: Could not load native events component."

Comment: That's a different error. It is based on Native Events. Try:

`profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new`

`profile.native_events = false`

`browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => profile)`

Comment: Actually, first you should make sure your Firefox and watir-webdriver versions are the latest ones. It could just be that your firefox version is mismatched with the Selenium version.

Comment: I tired with your code as well did not work. I tired in latest version of Firefox using selenium webdriver 2.44. .hover method will not work. Is there way around it ?

Comment: You've given me two separate exceptions and I've given the solution to each. What is your current code & stack trace? You can't still be getting a native events exception if you aren't using native events.